# Can machine learning algorithm learn to predict a "random" number from a generator to at least 50% accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning

Because all random number generators are all pseudo random number generators, can a machine learning algorithm eventually, with enough test data, learn to predict the next random number with 50% accuracy?

Comment: Belongs to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Define *predict the next random number*! If we are predicting random-bits, yeah sure, as random-guessing is working too (=50% accuracy). Is it possible to obtain more than 50%? I do think so, at least in theory, if your algorithm has enough *power*. He will approximate the underlying rng-process (a big enough Neural Network is able to do this). This applies to PRNS and CryptoPRNGs. In practice howewer i'm pretty sure this won't work, as there are too many non-linearities and learning is too hard, especially for CryptoPRNGs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating just random **bits** (0 or 1) then any method will get 50%, literally any, ML or not, trained on not. Anything besides direct exploitation of underlying random number generator (like reading the seed, and then using as a predictor the same random number generator). So the answer is yes.

If you consider more "numbers" then no, it is not possible, unless you do not have a valid random number generator. The weaker is the process and better your model you try to learn, it is easier to predict what is happening. For example if you know exactly how random number generator looks like, and this is just iterated function with some parameters f(x|params), where we start with some random seed s and parameters params and then x1=f(s|params), x2=f(x1|params), ... then you can learn using ML the state of such system, this is just about finding the "params", which fitted to f generate the actual values. Now - more complex f, the more complex is the problem. For typical random number generators f is too complex to learn, because you cannot observe any relation between close values - if you predict "5.8" and answer was "5.81" then next sample from your model might be "123" and from true generator "-2". This is completely chaotic process.

To sum up: this is possible only for very easy cases:

- either there are just 2 values (then there is nothing to learn, literally any method, which is not cheating, will get 50%)
- or random number generator is seriously flawed, and you have a knowledge about what type of flaw it is, and you can design a parametric model to approximate this.

Comment: The way you've worded this implies that if you randomly generate a number's bits you'll 50% success rate, but I assume you mean if you're generating a boolean. Unless this is what you actually meant, but this literally makes no sense to me, so please explain.

If you're generating a 32 bit random number, then the chance you guess it will be (1/2)^32, correct?

Comment: correct, I am talking about **generating a single bit**. In the sense that you have a sequence of bits, and at each time step you predict what will be the next one. If your stochastic process is not fully random, but it rather conditioned on previous ones (even in the simple Markov sense) - you will be able to get higher scores than chance. Changing the output alphabet to anything bigger does not change anything besides a single constant in the whole reasoning thus there was no point in introducing this additional complexity. Hope it makes it more clear.